# How does groovy add new methods to Java classes?

Tags: groovy

Consider the following snippet -

```
println String.class
```

The output is -

```
class java.lang.String
```

I was expecting some subclass of String since it contains many members that are not a part of the Java class. For example -

```
println String.methods.size()
```

`methods` is not a member of the Java class.

How does this magic happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groovy has a metaclass registry. When you call a method on a class the registry is inspected to see if a metaClass extension method exists for that class instance.

From the standard documentation -

> Each groovy object has a metaClass that is used to manage the dynamic
>   nature of the language. This class intercepts calls to groovy objects
>   to ensure that the appropriate grooviness can be added. [Source](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class)

Comment: Tim: I think I should have asked you the above question for the link - it was your answer.

Comment: They seem to have deleted anything before 2007