# println does not use overriden toString method in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have overriden `toString()` for my object:

```
class GroovyTest {
    static class TestObject {
        int a = 3
    }
    static main(def s) {
        TestObject.metaClass.toString = { -> 'silly'}   
        println new TestObject()
    }
}
```

Ignoring my custom `toString()` it uses the default `toString()` and prints:

```
GroovyTest$TestObject@195ed659
```

However if I manually invoke it like `println new TestObject().toString()` it works:

```
Silly
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you override a method in Groovy you are not actually modifying the Java byte code for the class. Your method gets added to a `metaClass` registry. The method calls on the object are intercepted and the `metaClass` is checked.

When a Groovy object is passed to Java code it will lose all of its Grooviness and become a `POJO` because method interception and `metaClass` checking will not happen there. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17946855/1345655).

`println` internally uses `System.out.println` which bypasses the Groovy method interception and invokes `Object.toString()`.